# Database table definition features reference

Tags: database

I am looking for some reference which can help me in finding out the **DDL** (Data Definition Language) differences in multiple databases (*Oracle, DB2, Sybase, SQL Server, MySQL, Firebird, PostgreSQL, Ingres, HSQL, H2 Database, Derby*).

- What all constraints are supported by each database?
- Whether table/column comments are supported or not?
- Auto increment of column is possible or not?
- information schema is available to find out the schema details etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a page with [extensive comparison of database engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems).